# How to save checked status for checkbox in data grid view c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, checkbox, save

I am working in c# windows application populate record from sql server to data grid view, with dynamic checkbox facility in each row. i want to select selected rows for some purpose via checkbox of that particular row. till  now i successfully achieve my target. but i'm facing a minor issue regarding saving a checked status, Example i want to check only those records whose Name = Max i have a textbox in that textbox i call text chnage event with like Query

Code for Filter by name:

```
 try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlConnection con = null; Ranks rank = new Ranks();
            con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Records where Name like @Name order by Pno";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + FilterByNameTextbox.Text.Trim() + "%");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter1.Fill(dt);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            Make_fields_Colorful();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        }
```

if i write Max in filter by name textbox it would return 3 records with name starts with max using like query as i mention code above. so i only check 2 records out of 3 using dynamic checkbox, till now my code runs perfectly. Now i want to check records which name starts from Ali, now when i write ali in my filter by name textbox it will return rows where name like ali , but problem comes here it will remove my previous checked records, so how i would able to save checked records for both max and ali's rows:

Code for adding dynamic checkboxes in each row

```
   DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
        checkBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Report";
        checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Report";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(10, checkBoxColumn);
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 100;
        dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 50;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintaining state of checkboxes while filtering record using textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644129/maintaining-state-of-checkboxes-while-filtering-record-using-textbox)

Comment: This is a copy+paste duplicate of your previous question, and even includes the same typos.

Answer (score 1):

In order persist with the check box selection, you would require to save the check box state for each row.

**Step 1**

Add new column in `Record` table. 
eg. `CheckState of BIT` (Here `BIT` SQL Server Column Type which stores Boolean values)

**Step 2**

Now add the code to intercept Check Box state change by utilizing the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event of the `DataGridView`. 
Below is the sample code;

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
    {
        bool checkVal = (Boolean)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;       // Check box state value
        int checkBoxState = checkVal ? 1 : 0;       // 1 - TRUE, 0 - FALSE

        // Now save the check box state change in the database table.

        // You would need a key field to distinguish the record in the DB table
        // As per the code you had provided you could do something similar to below, assuming that the Pno column is the key field/ unique

        int keyValue = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Pno"].Value;

        // Save the changes by passing checkBoxState and keyValue accordingly
        SetNewUploadFileForGrantAppID(checkBoxState, keyValue);
    }
}
```

Function to call the SQL Server stored procedure.

```
    private void SetNewUploadFileForGrantAppID(int pIntRecordKeyValue, int pIntCheckBoxStatus)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);

        try
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.usp_SetRecordCheckStatus";
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIntRecordKeyValue", pIntRecordKeyValue);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIntCheckBoxStatus", pIntCheckBoxStatus);
            connection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Step 3**

Create [SQL Server Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) to save the changes

Eg.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SetRecordCheckStatus]
    @pIntRecordKeyValue INT,
    @pIntCheckBoxStatus INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.Record
        SET CheckState = @pIntCheckBoxStatus
        WHERE Pno = @pIntCheckBoxStatus
END
GO
```

Comment: Dear sir thank you for your code , i am new in c# please also tell me how to       
save the check box state change in the database table.
and how Save the changes by passing checkBoxState and sKeyValue accordingly

Comment: bool checkVal = (Boolean)CustomersList.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue;

in above line what is  CustomersList??

Comment: Sorry changed that to `dataGridView1`.

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad, please refer the updated answer with details on how to save the changes.

Comment: Dear sir thank you till now i successfully implement the  code, in my database Bit value successfully stored now whats the next step, now i want to select records for max as well as ali at same time

Comment: sir can i share screen to you will you help me to code i m so much stuck

Comment: Your requirements looks to be ever changing ;-). You have decide on how you are planning to display the data, i.e. whether based on an filter expression or bring down data based on multiple search conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you by doing the code for you. Don't give up and let yourself down, try to go through articles/ resources on programming in general and you'd be able to get the hang of coding [C# Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) [C# Fundamentals for Absolute Beginners](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=Lvld4EQIC_2706218949). Good Luck!

Comment: sir my data is displaying already, issue is when i select records via checkbox where name like "max" , then i have a text box which have text change event for Fiterby name when i want to check records via checkbox for name like "ali", its shows me records where name like ali but my previous checked rows unchecked it that case , i want to hold all the checked rows by performing filerbyname text change event

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, once you have set up your project to save the checkbox state, all you have to do is type in the search text box to reload the data.

Comment: In below line
 string sKeyValue = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();

it always return same SKeyValue for all checked records

Comment: I am able to get the unique ID for each row with that code. Include `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());` in `dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` to get a visual confirmation on the `Id` for each row. Also please check the database table ensure the `Id` column has unique values. NOTE: Only issue I noticed was the `dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` getting fired twice simultaneously.

Comment: Upvoted for encouraging the question author to stand on their own two feet. The question was asked in duplicate, and some other poor sod is also helping on the same problem.