# Maintaining state of checkboxes while filtering record using textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a C# windows application to populate records from SQL Server to data grid view, with dynamic checkbox facility in each row. I want to select selected rows for some purpose via checkbox of that particular row. Till now I successfully achieve my target, but I'm facing a minor issue regarding saving a checked status.

For example I want to check only those records whose Name = Max. I have a textbox in that textbox I call text change event with like Query:

```
 try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlConnection con = null; Ranks rank = new Ranks();
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);
        con.Open();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Records where Name like @Name order by Pno";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + FilterByNameTextbox.Text.Trim() + "%");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter1.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        Make_fields_Colorful();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
```

If I write Max in filter by name textbox it would return 3 records with name starts with max using like query as I mention code above. So I only check 2 records out of 3 using dynamic checkbox, till now my code runs perfectly. Now I want to check records which name starts from Ali, now when I write ali in my filter by name textbox it will return rows where name like ali , but problem comes here it will remove my previous checked records, so how I would able to save checked records for both max and ali's rows:

Code for adding dynamic checkboxes in each row

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
    checkBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "Report";
    checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Report";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(10, checkBoxColumn);
    dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 100;
    dataGridView1.Columns[10].Width = 50;
```

Images:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3ref.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiE3D.png)

Comment: This question [has been asked twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642434/how-to-save-checked-status-for-checkbox-in-data-grid-view-c-sharp-windows-applic), I have voted to put the other one on hold.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you achieve this by caching selected rows, first you should have a list of cached rows:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> CachedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
```

then add event handler on cell value change like the following:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += view_CellValueChanged;
```

and the handler should check if the column changed is the checkbox and checked, should be something like the following:

```
try
{
    if(e.ColumnIndex == indexOfCheckBoxColumn)
    {
       if((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == true)
       {
        CachedRows.Add((DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Clone());
       }
       else if (CachedRows.Contains(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]))//Validate if this works, if not you should associate each row with unique key like for example (id) using a dictionary
       {
          CachedRows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
       }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

then after the filter changes, re-add the cached rows again, so code becomes:

```
try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlConnection con = null; Ranks rank = new Ranks();
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);
        con.Open();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Records where Name like @Name order by Pno";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "%" + FilterByNameTextbox.Text.Trim() + "%");
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter1.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //add folowing
        if (CachedRows.Any())
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(CachedRows.ToArray());
            CachedRows.Clear();
        }
        Make_fields_Colorful();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ,

please let me know where to add 

this line?

dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += view_CellValueChanged;

Comment: one thing more when i add 

following line 

 if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == true)

it will give error

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool'

Comment: i change if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == true)
to

 if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value)

now value come null thats why it through error
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad try adding the dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += view_CellValueChanged after initializing (dataGridView1 = new  dataGridView1()), and I suggest wrapping the event handler with try catch

Comment: i successfully add event handler, but i am facing an error when records added in cachedRows some of the rows having index= -1 which give error

Comment: sir where to add these lines

if (CachedRows.Any())
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.AddRange(CachedRows.ToArray());
}

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad check updated answer, note using clone() before adding a cached row

Comment: Still index = -1

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad well index by default before adding is -1, after adding it will be changed inside dataGridView1.Rows collection, in case it is still a problem for each time create a new row instead with values from original row, but after using clone there should be no problem in adding a new row, however I don't have a full code to run these are just guidelines that I hope they help, so you can come up with a workaround for the problem you are facing :)